# How to Trace variables used in 4000 Line code Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which has 4000 lines of code it is in reporting and when I run the procedure, I get a `NULL` value somewhere in that code.  How can I best trace or track at what line that `NULL` value is being assigned?

Suppose I am using a variable such as `getName` and I am assigning a value to the variable in the procedure... How should I trace the values of `getName` or how I can watch this variable after assigning a value to it?

Comment: Don't have a 4000-line procedure.

Comment: Do you have any idea where to start looking?  You have `sql-server-2008`, pretty sure `SSMS` there has debugging tools you could use.

Comment: @Adam Wenger yes you are right but there are lots of variable. is it going to help me to trace but i have to debug each line at every time say suppose i am using a loop in code that loop is of 100 times running so i need to debug 100 times it will take a lot of time.is there any shortest method to do ?

Comment: As far as the loop, if you are confident the loop is not the cause, you can use the `Run To Cursor` option in debugging to jump through a lot of the procedure to determine a smaller area to examine.  You an also use this option to jump 1000 lines or so at a time to help narrow down your area to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 4000 line stored procedure is far too large. If you are putting this much logic in a stored procedure, you should think about refactoring into for example a business layer/data access approach.